# NullPointerException in Eclipse itself

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I started working on a project recently and after I imported it in Eclipse (the usual way, `File` -> `Import` -> `Existing Projects` into Workspace) it started giving me this strange error. The project has a little red icon, like it is not configure properly, that is really bugging me.

The error below happens also when I click on Project Facets. When I try to click OK it alerts me with the usual java-style `NullPointerException`. Otherwise, the project works just fine. I'm using `Eclipse Kepler`.

[image: eclipse-error]

Comment: how about other eclipse versions?

Comment: go to Window -> Show View -> others -> Problem Tab once. check if you can see anything there.

Comment: Erros message in Problem tab: "This project has the JPA facet, but no JPA project could be created."

Answer (score 1):

Examine the error log view,  select appropriate problem (probably the JPA error message) and open it.  See if there is a stack trace present.  this may point more directly to the issue at hand.  Suggest possibly reporting it to Eclipse foundation at the bugzilla site.

(edit: corrected view name.  thanks)

Comment: Not the problems view. You want to look at Error Log view for issues with Eclipse.

Comment: The problems view shows what I posted in a comment to my original post. Also, there are no problems in the project, except for that preferences page on the picture. @KonstantinKomissarchik I'll check this view.